# Trying to figure out why .push() method is breaking my application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am having an issue where a certain line is breaking my application using the `push` method to add a string to an array.

Here is the part of the method I am having issues with:

```
result = result['cm:property-placeholder']['cm:default-properties'][0]['cm:property']
this.regex = new RegExp(`${this.uiListElement[0].$.id}.${this.uiListElement[0].UIElement[0].$.id}`);
      console.log(this.regex);
      let m;
      for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if ((m = this.regex.exec(result[i].$.name)) !== null) {

          m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
            console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
            
            console.log(match);
            this.uiListElement[0].UIElement[0].$.regex.push(match);
            
          });
        
        }
      }
```

Debugging the application, everything works up until the line: `this.uiListElement[0].UIElement[0].$.regex.push(match);`

I then recieve the error:

`TypeError: cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Here is the interface:

```
export interface UIListElement {
    $: { id: string; name: string; }
    UIElement:[
    {
        $: 
        {
            id: string;
            maxlength: string;
            name: string;
            required: string;
            type: string;
            value: any;
            regex: string[];
        }
    }]
}
```

I want to be able to add whatever value is in `match` to my `regex` property in my `UIListElement` interface.

Comment: `everything works up until the line` ← so what happens at that line? Be specific and include state of `this` at that point if possible. Is something in the chain `this.uiListElement[0].UIElement[0].$.regex` evaluating to undefined? Is `this.uiListElement[0].UIElement[0].$.regex` an array? Is it succeeding but not behaving as expected after? Please do not make us guess what is happening in your code.

Comment: @Igor Good catch. I thought I had included the error and I hadn't. Added

Comment: So you do not have an array by that name `regex`. Either create a new one or assign one to it. Do this with a simple `if` truthy check before hand `if (!this.uiListElement[0].UIElement[0].$.regex) { this.uiListElement[0].UIElement[0].$.regex  = []; }`

Comment: @Igor I do. It's included in the interface at the bottom of the question

Comment: there should be ``,`` instead of ``;`` inside of objects, no?

Comment: An interface is *not* an implementation or an instance. It is a contract of expectations but it seems the actual contract (read interface) should be updated to read `regex?: string[] | undefined;` as the field is / can be `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments above I realized I hadn't initialized an array for each `match` to be pushed into my array. Added `this.uiListElement[0].UIElement[0].$.regex  = [];` and it resolved my issue.